# Smooth Line graph in Android GraphView

Tags: android-graphview

It is possible to make line graph more smooth? If my data have not much points on graph?

Comment: Hi, Did you find out any solution? I'm too looking for same

Answer (score 1):

You can try to smooth the data first, with a Savitzky Golay filter for example, and then send it to the GraphView.

A sample of this filter can be found here: [Savitzky-Golay Filter](http://orangepalantir.org/ijplugins/src/SavitzkyGolayFilter.html)